# Sticky Keys in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux, accessibility

I followed [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Accessibility#Sticky_keys_with_systemd) tutorial but it didn't work.

```
keymaps 0-2,4-5,8,12
keycode 37  = SCtrl
keycode 50  = SShift
keycode 64  = SAlt
keycode 105 = SCtrl
keycode 62  = SShift
keycode 108 = SAlt
```

and then did a `loadkeys` but it didn't work.

I just use a window manager called `jwm` with `tint2`. Any good solutions in pure Linux?